# Best way to store gasoline for a generator

Tags: hydrocarbons

For my lawn power-tools, my normal regime is to store 2-galleons of 85-octane gas, purchased in the spring, and treated with Sta-Bil. This lasts me through the season. Now, however, I'm looking into getting a generator. This gas may not be used within the season, so longer-term storage considerations come into play (though, some rotation scheme inclusive of my power-tool usage may make sense). So what combinations of octanes, ethonal/non-ethanol containing gas, and sta-bil should I consider and why? And what form of rotation - should I put ever everything in a larger tank and mix it with "fresher" gas. Keep things separate in smaller containers? Seal some up with a treatment of some kind and not touch it? And again, why?

Comment: How much gas does the generator use per day? How many days supply for generator? Where do you store the gas?

Comment: What is that "sta-bil" supposed to do? If you keep the fuel in a closed cannister, and outside of the sunlight (because of the ethanol), it will stay fine forever. Temperature swings in a ventilated tank make water condense into the fuel, but that´s already the worst that could happen, imo.

Comment: "What is that "sta-bil" supposed to do" - I don't know, that is why I asked on the chemistry forum ;)

Comment: "Where do you store the gas?" - backyard shed.

Comment: " How many days supply for generator? " - I'd like to keep enough for a week of continuous daytime-use. I'm still looking into different models, so I don't yet know consumption rates.

Answer (score 2):

I have a small generator that burns a gallon in about 15 hours Storage is about 6 gal in 1 and 2 gal containers. I use the same gas in mower and other small engines, so I rotate the inventory . My combined use is about 4 gal per year so the average storage life is roughly 16 months , this has been no problem. Another option is to use old gasoline in a car in order to refresh the stock. I store it in a garden shed as I don't want that volume in a garage.